# How to send and recieve multivariables to php using json and array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I want to send some data from a form to a PHP file using jQuery. I've searched and I noticed I have to send the data as JSON and receive multiple variables as an array. However I'm Completely confused it's not working.

```html
<input id="username" type="text" class="inputBox">
<input id="password" type="password" class="inputBox">
<button id="submitLogin" class="submitLogin">login</button>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test1"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitLogin").click(function() {
    var superuser = $("#username").val();
    var superpass = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'http://localhost/mainclinic/controllers/login/login.php',
      dataType: 'application/json',
      data: {
        loginid: superuser,
        loginpass: superpass
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
        $('#test').html(result[0]);
        $('#test1').html(result[1]);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```php
<?php
  include "../config.php";

  if (!$db) 
  {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
  {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['loginid']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['loginpass']);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM superusers WHERE docid = '$username' and doccpass = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
      $array = array(success, $username);
      echo json_encode($array);
    }
    else
    {
      $array = array(failed, nousername);
      echo json_encode($array);
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: console.log(result) in success & check response

Comment: What is `nousername`? is it a string?

Comment: Yeah it's string

Comment: 'It's not working' is very broad. Have you determined exactly where this is failing? Is it the client side JS or the PHP? Are the values being sent in the request? What's being received? We need much more information to be able to help diagnose the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change This section to this:

```
$.ajax
    ({
        type:"POST",
        url:'http://localhost/mainclinic/controllers/login/login.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data:{loginid:superuser,loginpass:superpass},
        cache: false,
        success:function (result) {
            $('#test').html(result.status);
            $('#test1').html(result.result);
        }
    })
```

And Php code like this:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $array = array('status' => 'success', 'result' => $username);
    echo json_encode($array);
}else
{
    $array = array('status' => 'failed', 'result' => 'nousername');
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```